# How to complete gem collector challenge

Tags: the-sims-3

The game says that you have to find 10 different gems to complete this challenge.

I have collected the following gems:

- blue topaz
- diamond
- rainbow gem
- ruby
- smoky quartz
- yellow sapphire
- alabaster
- amethyst
- citrine
- jade
- lapis lazuli
- quartz
- septarian nodule
- soulpeace
- tiberium
- bloodstone
- smithsonite
- emerald

which is over 10 however it says that I have only collected 2 gems, (4% completed).

Am I missing something?

I still haven't gotten the heart-shaped cut yet to master inventor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because mining gems does not count towards the "10" total.

You must find them in the neighborhood for them to count towards this challenge.

Comment: thats pretty hard, i dont have collection helper reward yet

Comment: @DovahVinn  what do you mean by **mining gems**?

Comment: @DovahVinn that's why it's called a challenge ;)